# Is there a simple term or standard definition for a category in which each hom set has a commutative monoid structure?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Is there a simple term or standard definition for a category in which each hom set has a commutative monoid structure?

I was working with the category of matrices. But I only needed to use that each hom set has a zero morphism, and that we can add morphisms. So I don't need that every morphism has an addititve inverse.

I found stuff on enriched categories, but it seemed to be overly complicated for the purpose that I was using it for.

Or can I simply define an 'commutative monoid catgory' as a category with zero morphisms, and for each hom set a '+' operation that is associative and commutative, and it has the property that $a + 0 = 0 = 0 + a$?

Are there any foundational issues with such a definition?

Comment: A category enriched in commutative monoids sounds like exactly what you're describing except that it includes some "compatibility" conditions between composition and $+$ that I suspect you do want. In general, many of the topics discussed in enriched category theory are probably relevant as you'd want to have a notion of functor that respects the structure, etc.

Comment: With the appropriate compatibilities, “semiadditive category.”

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I read here (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct) that a semi-additive category has all finite biproducts. And since the empty biproduct is the zero object, it contains the zero object. However, the category of matrices, where we take as objects $1,2,\ldots$ has no zero object. I looked into adding the zero object, but things get messy and it would not be usefull. So are you sure about "semiadditive"?

Comment: @JensWagemaker The category of matrices should have a zero object (so you should take $0$ as an object in it), since it should be equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces...

Comment: @ArnaudD Isn't that a matter of definition? If I exclude the $0$ object I still get Objects (natural numbers), Morphisms (matrices) and composition (matrix multiplication). And these satisfy the axioms of a category? Or am I mistaking?

Comment: Yes, of course, it is a category. What I mean is that you *can* include a zero object, and since one of the main point of matrices is that they represent linear maps, one could argue that you *should* include the zero object.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you for thinking along! I also thought about including the zero object since it would make a nicer story with the 'chosing coordinates functor' from the category of finite vector spaces with a basis. With that functor we map a vector space to its dimension. Ofcourse the image of the zero dimensional vector space would be this zero object. However, this seemed to be the only advantage of including it. In the rest of my story the zero object causes a lot of trouble because we need to define everyting separateldly for the zero object and it causes many case distinctions.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Also from a computational point the zero object seemed not usefull. From a computational point the zero morphisms are interesting (for me), and we have these anyway (the zero matrices).